# SQL get users details by ids from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, express, mariadb

I have problem to get data for posts table by CONCAT **first_name** & **last_name** for **created_by** and **edited_by** columns from users table.
Here's the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
  id    varchar(300),
  title     varchar(300),
  created_by    varchar(300),
  edited_by     varchar(255)
);
```

| id | title | created_by | edited_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lorem | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | ipsum | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | lorem ipsum | 2 | 2 |

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
     id     varchar(300),
     first_name     varchar(300),
     last_name  varchar(300),
        varchar(255)
);
```

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | doe |
| 2 | will | smith |

Now I want to SELECT posts table and make the output like below

| id | title | created_by | edited_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lorem | john doe | will smith |
| 2 | ipsum | john doe | john doe |
| 3 | lorem ipsum | will smith | will smith |

The problem is I want to change the id in posts table with users first & last name. I'd tried this query:

```
SELECT 
  A.id,
  A.title,
  CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) created_by,
  CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) edited_by
FROM posts A
INNER JOIN users B ON A.created_by = B.id
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What query have you written? What problems occur with it?

Comment: the problem is I want to change the id in posts table with users first & last name..
I'd tried this query 
SELECT
A.id, A.title,
CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) created_by,
CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) edited_by
FROM posts A
INNER JOIN users B 
ON
A.created_by = B.id

Comment: Okay, I have edited your request to put the information there. As shown by MtwStark, you must join the user table twice. And I wouldn't use arbitrary alias names. They make queries hard to read. Use `p` for `posts` and `u` or `users` for instance, not `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` users table twice:

```
SELECT A.id, A.title, CONCAT(B.first_name, ' ', B.last_name) created_by, CONCAT(C.first_name, ' ', C.last_name) edited_by 
FROM posts A 
INNER JOIN users B ON A.created_by = B.id
INNER JOIN users C ON A.edited_by = C.id
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know and I use it, I was just following the same schema of the example in the question